# Обработка данных от XSS

Tags: php, кодировка, безопасность, уязвимости

Необходимо обработать сообщение и засунуть в базу. Но как я не старался сделать безопасней утечки не получается. Вообщем делаю сайт на PHP. Мне нужно сделать защиту от XSS для комментариев на сайте. Обрабатываю вот как:

```
$test = trim(htmlspecialchars($test));
```

так же еще есть класс для обработки XSS из code-igniter, но  не помогает. Если сделать как я показал обработку, то за место `<script>` будет `[removed]`, а  теги меняются на кракозябры. Если же отправить текст вот такой

```
<sc<script>alert('XSS');</script></ript>
```

то при выполнение php ругается, но в базу его кидает. Хочется сделать как на этом сайте, то есть, все отображается в виде текста, а не опасного кода. =) Кто и что может посоветовать? Какие библиотеки, методы и т.д. ?

Comment: Приведите текст ошибки и пример "кракозябров", на которые у вас меняются теги после вызова htmlspecialchars

Comment: А еще лучше - ваш код

Comment: Если использовать исключительно теги HTML, то они отображаются нормально. Только вставить PHP код: <? echo "test"; ?> будет &lt;? echo "test"; ?&gt; , а про js вообще молчу. Так же, хочу сказать. Мой "не любимый" htmlspecialchars(); не спасет. Достаточно через Character Encoding Calculator перекодировать в URL код, вставить текст, то весь опасный код выполняется. Работает js,html,php. Вообщем эти стандартный методы не безопасны. Если знаете уже готовые библиотеки, то хотелось бы узнать названия. А если же нет, то хочу услышать методы реализации.

Comment: Вот мне интересно, как реализованы подобные вещи на CMS, форумах и т.д. Копался в форуме phpBB 3. Там все безопасность хорошая. Но в коде не нашел реализацию такой обработки.

Comment: Только что проверил у себя в скрипте <?php echo "test"; ?>, всё отображается нормально

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Алгоритм предельно прост:

- *При вставке в БД* экранируйте данные при помощи [mysql_real_escape_string](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-real-escape-string.php) или аналогичной функции. Никаких других преобразований при в ставке в БД делать не нужно.
- *При выводе в браузер*, полученные из БД данные, фильтруйте при помощи [htmlspecialchars](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.htmlspecialchars.php). Эта функция преобразует все HTML спецсимволы типа `<`, `>` или `&` в специальные [HTML-сущности](http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9C%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%B8_%D0%B2_HTML), которые никак не интерпретируются браузером, а только отображают соответствующий символ.

В большинстве случаев этих двух простых правил вполне достаточно, что бы защитится от XSS.

PS Тег `<pre>` нужен совсем для других целей.

PPS Текст `"&lt;? echo "test"; ?&gt;"` в браузере будет отображен как `"<? echo "test"; ?>"` (см. ссылки про [HTML-сущности](http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9C%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%B8_%D0%B2_HTML) и [структуру HTML документа](http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTML#.D0.A1.D1.82.D1.80.D1.83.D0.BA.D1.82.D1.83.D1.80.D0.B0_HTML-.D0.B4.D0.BE.D0.BA.D1.83.D0.BC.D0.B5.D0.BD.D1.82.D0.B0))

Comment: htmlspecialchars аффтару не падходит

Comment: AlexWindHope, Тролишь? Троли.

Comment: Я как-раз не тролю, вы создали 2 одинаковых вопроса, раскидали кучу пафосных комментариев а причиной тому оказалось то, что вы не знаете мат.части. ( а именно информации по ссылкам  HTML-сущности и структуру HTML документа )

При этом, когда вам неоднократно писали что проблема в вашем коде ( либо в вас самих ), вы уверенно это игнорировали и называли это тролингом.

По сути получилось так, что, для вас, правильным ответом на вопрос "Обработка данных от XSS" оказалась матчасть по HTML-сущностям. Не находите это странным?

Comment: И да - [здесь](http://hashcode.ru/questions/70635/%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B5%D1%82-%D0%B2%D1%8B%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F-%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B0) вы писали следующее: htmlspecialchars() не предлагать и функции наподобие ( это дабы не быть голословным )

Ну и в подтверждение моему комментарию

Comment: @AlexWindHope, может успокоитесь уже?

Боритесь за чистоту форума? - Так начните с себя.

Comment: Я не могу все знать. В процессе изучения. Я юзал поисковик чтобы найти ответ, но не нашел. Решил задать вопрос - ответа нет, а лишь указание на отсутствие этих знаний. Может framework у меня глючит, что так функция htmlspecialchars работает. Принцип уловил. Спасибо. ;)

Answer (score 0):

[htmlentities( )](http://php.net/manual/en/function.htmlentities.php)

---

```
 // дела :D
echo trim(htmlspecialchars('<sc<script>alert("EVEL HACK");</script></ript>'));
// -> скрипт не отрабатывает, сущности преобразованы, в чем проблема?

// по поводу PHP ругается - вы не задумывались что проблема в вашем коде? ;D
```

Могу я увидеть текст ошибки?

Comment: Я пробовал все стандартные функции php по обработке. Все плохо работают. Мне не нужны кракозябры. Нужно чтобы любой текст и  код выводился как обычный текст.

Comment: @Избранный как вы точно ник себе подобрали :DDD

Comment: Трололо. Лучше помог бы, чем тролить по сайту.

Comment: Почему-то представляется Fallout 2 и старейшина просит избранного найти исходники Google.

Comment: Код нормальный. Я всего лишь дорабатываю. Мне все-таки нужно выводить код как обычный текст. Слабо помочь? Прежде чем осуждать чужие наброски - предложил бы свои! ;-)

Comment: **скрипт не отрабатывает** - это главное, с чего ты взял что я тебя в чем-то обвиняю?

Я просто не пойму - с чего ты взял что ошибка PHP вызвана тем как ты обрабатываешь данные?

Comment: Все правильно не работает как надо код - виноват создатель. Смотри var_dump -ом переменные по ходу выполнения, а точнее ближе к месту проверки данных.

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте `striptags();`.

Comment: а вот этого **точно** делать ненадо =)

Comment: Что за бред?

Comment: Почему бред? Вырежет PHP и HTML теги, сделает пол работы.

Comment: Зачем вырезать то? Мне вот именно надо, чтобы и эти скрипты читал за текст и выводил как обычные сообщения.

Comment: Может быть до тебя уже дойдёт, что дело в твоём коде?

Comment: Дмитрий, тролить по всем моим темам с одной и той же темой занудства не лучший вариант. Удачи в "Трольстве" и показухой себя.

Comment: @Избранный, если кто и тролит так это вы( сознательно или нет )

Comment: Да, это правда. Я бы не занимался этим, если бы такие как ты не тролили в комментариях, а советовали другим. Жаль.

Answer (score 0):

Вот мой класс. Я его использую как раз для валидации различный параметров. 
Тебе нужен Validate.

Правда, в данном примере он проверяет контент на наличие sql_injection, xss.

Вобщем, если что, его ооочень просто расширить для своих нужд :)) И в качестве бонуса есть парочку дополнительных функций проверки валидности телефона, мыла.......

Вот класс:

```
    <?

interface i_validate_request {   
    public function check_login(LoginField $formField);         //Check validation login format
    public function check_mail(EmailField $formField);          //Check validation email format
    public function check_phone(PhoneField $formField);             //Check validation phone format
}

interface i_get_request {
    public function accept(i_validate_request $v);              //Check validation
}

class LoginField implements i_get_request {
    private $_login = null;

    public function setLogin($login) {
        $this->_login = $login;
    }
    public function getLogin() {
        return $this->_login;
    }
    public function accept(i_validate_request $v) {
        return $v->check_login($this);
    } 
}

class EmailField implements i_get_request {
    private $_email = null;

    public function setEmail($email) {
        $this->_email = $email;
    }

    public function getEmail() {
        return $this->_email;
    }

    public function accept(i_validate_request $v) {
        return $v->check_mail($this);
    }
}

class PhoneField implements i_get_request {
    private $_phoneNumber = null;

    public function setPhoneNumber($phoneNumber) {
        $this->_phoneNumber = $phoneNumber;
    }

    public function getPhoneNumber() {
        return $this->_phoneNumber;
    }

    public function accept(i_validate_request $v) {
        return $v->check_phone($this);
    }
}

class XssChecker implements i_validate_request {
    public function check_login(LoginField $formField) {
        return preg_match('/script/i', $formField->getLogin())>0 ? false : true;        
    }
    public function check_mail(EmailField $formField) {
        return preg_match('/script/i', $formField->getEmail())>0 ? false : true;
    }
    public function check_phone(PhoneField $formField) {
        return preg_match('/script/i', $formField->getPhoneNumber())>0 ? false : true;        
    }   
}

class SqlInjectionChecker implements i_validate_request {
    public function check_login(LoginField $formField) {
        return  preg_match('/\w*((\%27)|(\'))((\%6F)|o|(\%4F))((\%72)|r|(\%52))/ix',  $formField->getLogin())>0 ? false : true;        
    }
    public function check_mail(EmailField $formField) {
        return  preg_match('/\w*((\%27)|(\'))((\%6F)|o|(\%4F))((\%72)|r|(\%52))/ix',  $formField->getEmail())>0 ? false : true;
    }
    public function check_phone(PhoneField $formField) {
        return  preg_match('/\w*((\%27)|(\'))((\%6F)|o|(\%4F))((\%72)|r|(\%52))/ix',  $formField->getPhoneNumber())>0 ? false : true;        
    }
}

class FormatValidator implements i_validate_request {
    public function check_login(LoginField $formField) {
        return preg_match('/^[a-zA-Z ]+$/', $formField->getLogin())>0 ? true : false;        
    }
    public function check_mail(EmailField $formField) {
        return preg_match('/^[^@]+@[a-zA-Z0-9._-]+\.[a-zA-Z]+$/', $formField->getEmail())>0 ? true : false;
    }
    public function check_phone(PhoneField $formField) {
        return preg_match('/^8-[0-9]{3}-[0-9]{3}-[0-9]{4}$/i', $formField->getPhoneNumber())>0 ? true : false;  
    }
}

class Validate {

    private $paramFields,
        $formatValidator,
        $sqlInjectionChecker,
        $xssChecker;

    function __construct($login) {

        $formatValidator = new FormatValidator();
        $sqlInjectionChecker = new SqlInjectionChecker();
        $xssChecker = new XssChecker();

        $this->sqlInjectionChecker = $sqlInjectionChecker;
        $this->formatValidator = $formatValidator;
        $this->xssChecker = $xssChecker;

        $this->paramFields['LoginField'] =  new LoginField();
        $this->paramFields['LoginField']->setLogin($login);
    }
    public function main() {
        $paramFieldsWithErrors = array();       
        foreach($this->paramFields as $key) {
            if(     $key->accept($this->formatValidator) === false || 
                $key->accept($this->sqlInjectionChecker) === false ||  
                $key->accept($this->xssChecker) === false )
                $paramFieldsWithErrors[] = $key;
        }
        if(!$paramFieldsWithErrors)
            return true;
        return false;   
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: Класс хорош, но как раз валидация у меня на высшем уровне. Но, при валидации нужно пользователям соблюдать правила валидации чтобы не было ошибок. А если человека хочет написать какой-нибудь код, или что-нибудь в этом духе, то будут ошибки, а нужно чтобы любой текст и код читался и выводился как текст и не перекодировались символы.

Comment: на высшем уровне? Что-то сильно сомневаюсь в этом

Comment: Класс валидации, который я использую, популярен, уже используется много лет - Никто не жаловался! И он реально надежный.

Comment: популярен, никто не жаловался... О да - это аргументы...

Если что - IE тоже популярен, ниче?

Comment: @Избранный продлил мне жизнь ещё на 5 лет :)

Comment: Рад за вас.

Answer (score 0):

[image]

У меня всё хорошо, всё работает =|

Comment: все записи проходят через БД, нареканий нет